# Bootstrap columns inside ul

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to break my list into 2 rows depending on the screen size because on smaller screens the info is not properly shown (A,B,C... is just dummy info; real info consist in expressions which represents states) has you can see on the image

[image]

I have this code in my html

```css
.card {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.top {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 13% !important;
  padding-right: 13% !important
}

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #455A64;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 30px
}

#progressbar .text {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 16.6%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400
}

#progressbar .step0:before {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  content: "\e14c";
  color: #fff
}

#progressbar li:before {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px
}

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 16px;
  z-index: -1
}

#progressbar li:last-child:after {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%
}

#progressbar li:nth-child(2):after,
#progressbar li:nth-child(3):after,
#progressbar li:nth-child(4):after,
#progressbar li:nth-child(5):after,
#progressbar li:nth-child(6):after {
  left: -50%
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%
}

#progressbar li:last-child:after {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px
}

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #1678e9
}

#progressbar li.active:before {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  content: "\e876"
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="row d-flex px-3 justify-content-center top">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
      <h5>Consulta <span class="text-primary font-weight-bold">#6152</span></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul id="progressbar" class="text-center">
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 1 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">A</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 2 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">B</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 3 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">C</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 4 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">D</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 5 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">E</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 6 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">F</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this? I already tried to use bootstrap grid but I couldn't fix that. I also split the list into 2 but I guess that it's not the best solution because on a wider screen it still remains divided.

If there's a better and simpler solution for what I'm trying to do/have, I would like to know. Thanks in advance

UPDATE1: I solved the problem with the text assigning word-wrap to nomal on "#progessbar .text"

Comment: Not sure if this will completle solve your problem, but what if you use the `list-inline` class? (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#inline) on the `ul`

Comment: I'm reading about it but as I said to @95faf8e76605e973 I'm still giving my first steps into html and css. Every time I try to change someting it gets worse lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a media query that gives the `li` `width: 33%;` on screens smaller than 700px.

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #progressbar li {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

so they will be in 2 rows of 3

```css
.card {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.top {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 13% !important;
  padding-right: 13% !important
}

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #455A64;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 30px
}

#progressbar .text {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 16.6%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400
}

#progressbar .step0:before {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  content: "\e14c";
  color: #fff
}

#progressbar li:before {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px
}

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 16px;
  z-index: -1
}

#progressbar li:last-child:after {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%
}

#progressbar li:nth-child(2):after,
#progressbar li:nth-child(3):after,
#progressbar li:nth-child(4):after,
#progressbar li:nth-child(5):after,
#progressbar li:nth-child(6):after {
  left: -50%
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%
}

#progressbar li:last-child:after {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px
}

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #1678e9
}

#progressbar li.active:before {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  content: "\e876"
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #progressbar li {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <div class="row d-flex px-3 justify-content-center top">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
      <h5>Consulta <span class="text-primary font-weight-bold">#6152</span></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul id="progressbar" class="text-center">
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 1 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">A</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 2 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">B</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 3 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">C</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 4 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">D</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 5 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">E</div>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="estado >= 6 ? 'active step0' : 'step0'">
          <div class="text">F</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to break my list into 2 rows depending on the screen size ... How can I solve this? I already tried to use bootstrap grid but I
> couldn't fix that. I also split the list into 2 but I guess that it's
> not the best solution because on a wider screen it still remains
> divided.

You can still salvage your "split the list into 2" implementation. Simply use the [Bootstrap Flex Utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/).
Test the code below on wide screen / small screen. You will see that the content wraps into 2 on smaller screens and maintain a straight 1 row for wide screens. 
For responsive purposes, simply assign a `min-width` to the list containers (`ul.sample-list` in this case), so you can target when to start wrapping the content. You are going to want to do this inside [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```css
.sample-list {
  padding: 0;
}

.estado {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <ul class="sample-list d-flex">
    <li class="estado">Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li class="estado">Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li class="estado">Lorem ipsum</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sample-list d-flex">
    <li class="estado">Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li class="estado">Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li class="estado">Lorem ipsum</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to implement your solution adapted to my code but it didn't work. Maybe I made some mistake as I'm not very good with html and css (still giving the first steps into it). I was able to divide it into 2 lists and put them into 2 rows or a single one depending on the screen size. However, on the single row, they kept apart just like if they were on 2 columns. I also have to modify the width on #progressbar li depending on the number of rows (one row it will be 16.6% but if it's 2 rows it will be 33.33% )

Comment: "However, on the single row, they kept apart just like if they were on 2 columns". Perhaps you have some padding or margin that separate the two. Simply get rid of these and they should appear as a single group instead of 2 columns.

Comment: I guess I dont have any of them. They just dont use all the space. Besides, there's still the problem with the width of each element that need to be changed depending on the screen. Btw, "estado" is not a class but a variable that I use to know which classes I'll assign for each li element. I changed the image on the original post so people can see the all problem: the text get all messed up and I think the best solution is to divide it into 2 rows